# Horizontal Material-ui Divider is not getting displayed using as a React Component. How to resolve this issue?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using `Divider` as a React Component but it is not getting displayed. I have tried reading the API documentation but I couldn't understand the usage of it and demos. How can this issue be resolved?

This is how it is displayed

[image]

Component:

```
import './styles.css';
import Products from '../../../Assets/Products.png';
import Divider  from '../../../../node_modules/@material-ui/core/Divider';

const ProductsSection = () => {
    return (
        <div className="ProductContainer">
            <p>INSTALLED OVER 10 LAKHS STAR RATED PUMPSETS ACROSS THE COUNTRY RESULTING IN A CUMULATIVE SAVING OF MORE THAN 9,000 MILLION UNITS OF POWER FOR THE NATION.</p>
            <img id="ProductImage" src={Products} alt="Products" />
            <p>Valves - Pumps - Pipes - IoT Drives & Controllers - Wires & Cables - Solar Systems - Motors </p>
            <Divider variant="middle"/>
            <p>C.R.I. FLUID SYSTEMS PRODUCTS CATER TO DIVERSE SEGMENTS</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductsSection;
```

Comment: Do you see a `<hr>` in your DOM? I couldn't reproduce the issue in [my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-lamport-11dj7?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Yes. There is a `<hr>` tag in the DOM. ```<hr class="MuiDivider-root MuiDivider-middle">```

Comment: Then maybe your styles are overwritten. Is there anything in the "rules" tab of your developer tools, when seleting the `<hr>`?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and for me it was caused by flexbox
I fixed it by giving the divider a width of 100%
`<Divider style={{width:'100%'}} />`

Comment: It may be useful to also set `backgroundColor` as whatever specified color you desire. For mine, nothing appeared until after I specified it: `<Divider style={{backgroundColor: "black", width:'100%'}} />`